# If Statement: <Condition> Unexpected This Time

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I had this kind of code in my program. For some reason, it gives an error that says

1!==3 was unexpected at this time. Any solution?

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set x=1
if x==1 (
    set y=321
    if !y:~0,1!==3 ( echo GOOOO)
)
endlocal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL enableDelayedExpansion
SET "x=1"
if %x%==1 (
    set "y=321"
    if "!y:~0,1!"=="3" ECHO GOOOO
)
endlocal
```